# Is it possible to convert between akka.http.javadsl.server.Route and akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route

Tags: scala, akka-http

I was wondering if it is possible to convert an instance of one to and instance of the other. If so, then how would I do it? I haven't found any mention of this in the akka-http docs.
I am trying to write a class that implements a Java interface that returns the base route of a akka-http application, but internally I want to implement the class in Scala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`javadsl.server.Route` is actually implemented by an adapter wrapping a `scaladsl.server.Route` (the concrete class is called `RouteAdapter`). You can move around between the two by doing

```
val scalaRoute = get { complete("OK") } // akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route

val javaRoute = RouteAdapter(scalaRoute) // extends akka.http.javadsl.server.Route

val backToScalaRoute = RouteAdapter(scalaRoute).delegate // akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route
```

Comment: So, is there a simple way of going the other way around: from a `akka.http.javadsl.server.Route` to a `akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route`, preferably without casting the java Route to RouteAdapter?

Comment: I do not see a way that wouldn't involve the casting.